# Entity Framework: Get executed query including parameter types

Tags: c#, entity-framework

is there a way to get the executed query including the parameters for `ObjectQuery<T>` instances in EF1?
I can do `ToTraceString` but that returns only the query, but not the parameters.
`ObjectQuery<T>` has a property `Parameters`, but they live in the .NET world, i.e. the value of `ParameterType` is `System.String` and not `varchar(15)`.
How do I get this info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EF tracing provider](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers) or some commercial tools like:

- [Hugati Query Profiler](http://www.huagati.com/L2SProfiler/)
- [Entity framework profiler](http://efprof.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Do I understand this correctly: There is no built in way?

Comment: Yes you understand it correctly :) Btw here is whole article about available tools: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490349.aspx